# The way that copy data to a linear tiled image(not using stage buffer)when the format of image is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM seems not work correctly?

Tags: file-upload, rendering, textures, vulkan, off-screen

There are two ways that can copy data to image(using stage buffer or not).In the first way that using stage buffer, when the image format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM or VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM, it works correctly.But in the way that not using stage buffer, the image format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, it works well. While changing the format to VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM, the result of sample is not correct.The source data can be assured correct when setting different image format .

The code used is from [https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/texture/texture.cpp](https://www.stackoverflow.com/

```
        if (0/*useStaging*/) {
            // Copy data to an optimal tiled image
            // This loads the texture data into a host local buffer that is copied to the optimal tiled image on the device

            // Create a host-visible staging buffer that contains the raw image data
            // This buffer will be the data source for copying texture data to the optimal tiled image on the device
            VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
            VkDeviceMemory stagingMemory;

            VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreateInfo = vks::initializers::bufferCreateInfo();
            bufferCreateInfo.size = ktxTextureSize;
            // This buffer is used as a transfer source for the buffer copy
            bufferCreateInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;
            bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferCreateInfo, nullptr, &stagingBuffer));

            // Get memory requirements for the staging buffer (alignment, memory type bits)
            vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, stagingBuffer, &memReqs);
            memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
            // Get memory type index for a host visible buffer
            memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &stagingMemory));
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindBufferMemory(device, stagingBuffer, stagingMemory, 0));

            // Copy texture data into host local staging buffer
            uint8_t *data;
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkMapMemory(device, stagingMemory, 0, memReqs.size, 0, (void **)&data));
            memcpy(data, ktxTextureData, ktxTextureSize);
            vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingMemory);

            // Setup buffer copy regions for each mip level
            std::vector<VkBufferImageCopy> bufferCopyRegions;
            uint32_t offset = 0;

            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < texture.mipLevels; i++) {
                // Calculate offset into staging buffer for the current mip level
                ktx_size_t offset;
                KTX_error_code ret = ktxTexture_GetImageOffset(ktxTexture, i, 0, 0, &offset);
                assert(ret == KTX_SUCCESS);
                // Setup a buffer image copy structure for the current mip level
                VkBufferImageCopy bufferCopyRegion = {};
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.mipLevel = i;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.width = ktxTexture->baseWidth >> i;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.height = ktxTexture->baseHeight >> i;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.depth = 1;
                bufferCopyRegion.bufferOffset = offset;
                bufferCopyRegions.push_back(bufferCopyRegion);
            }

            // Create optimal tiled target image on the device
            VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = vks::initializers::imageCreateInfo();
            imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
            imageCreateInfo.format = format;
            imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = texture.mipLevels;
            imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
            imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
            imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
            imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
            // Set initial layout of the image to undefined
            imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
            imageCreateInfo.extent = { texture.width, texture.height, 1 };
            imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &texture.image));

            vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, texture.image, &memReqs);
            memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
            memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &texture.deviceMemory));
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, texture.image, texture.deviceMemory, 0));

            VkCommandBuffer copyCmd = vulkanDevice->createCommandBuffer(VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY, true);

            // Image memory barriers for the texture image

            // The sub resource range describes the regions of the image that will be transitioned using the memory barriers below
            VkImageSubresourceRange subresourceRange = {};
            // Image only contains color data
            subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
            // Start at first mip level
            subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
            // We will transition on all mip levels
            subresourceRange.levelCount = texture.mipLevels;
            // The 2D texture only has one layer
            subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

            // Transition the texture image layout to transfer target, so we can safely copy our buffer data to it.
            VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = vks::initializers::imageMemoryBarrier();;
            imageMemoryBarrier.image = texture.image;
            imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange = subresourceRange;
            imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
            imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
            imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;

            // Insert a memory dependency at the proper pipeline stages that will execute the image layout transition
            // Source pipeline stage is host write/read execution (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT)
            // Destination pipeline stage is copy command execution (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT)
            vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
                copyCmd,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                0,
                0, nullptr,
                0, nullptr,
                1, &imageMemoryBarrier);

            // Copy mip levels from staging buffer
            vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(
                copyCmd,
                stagingBuffer,
                texture.image,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                static_cast<uint32_t>(bufferCopyRegions.size()),
                bufferCopyRegions.data());

            // Once the data has been uploaded we transfer to the texture image to the shader read layout, so it can be sampled from
            imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
            imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

            // Insert a memory dependency at the proper pipeline stages that will execute the image layout transition
            // Source pipeline stage is copy command execution (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT)
            // Destination pipeline stage fragment shader access (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT)
            vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
                copyCmd,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                0,
                0, nullptr,
                0, nullptr,
                1, &imageMemoryBarrier);

            // Store current layout for later reuse
            texture.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

            vulkanDevice->flushCommandBuffer(copyCmd, queue, true);

            // Clean up staging resources
            vkFreeMemory(device, stagingMemory, nullptr);
            vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
        } else {
            // Copy data to a linear tiled image

            VkImage mappableImage;
            VkDeviceMemory mappableMemory;

            // Load mip map level 0 to linear tiling image
            VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = vks::initializers::imageCreateInfo();
            imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
            imageCreateInfo.format = format;
            imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 1;
            imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
            imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
            imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
            imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
            imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
            imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED;
            imageCreateInfo.extent = { texture.width, texture.height, 1 };
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &mappableImage));

            // Get memory requirements for this image like size and alignment
            vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, mappableImage, &memReqs);
            // Set memory allocation size to required memory size
            memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
            // Get memory type that can be mapped to host memory
            memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &mappableMemory));
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, mappableImage, mappableMemory, 0));

            // Map image memory
            void *data;
            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkMapMemory(device, mappableMemory, 0, memReqs.size, 0, &data));
            // Copy image data of the first mip level into memory
            memcpy(data, ktxTextureData, memReqs.size);
            vkUnmapMemory(device, mappableMemory);

            // Linear tiled images don't need to be staged and can be directly used as textures
            texture.image = mappableImage;
            texture.deviceMemory = mappableMemory;
            texture.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

            // Setup image memory barrier transfer image to shader read layout
            VkCommandBuffer copyCmd = vulkanDevice->createCommandBuffer(VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY, true);

            // The sub resource range describes the regions of the image we will be transition
            VkImageSubresourceRange subresourceRange = {};
            subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
            subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
            subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
            subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

            // Transition the texture image layout to shader read, so it can be sampled from
            VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = vks::initializers::imageMemoryBarrier();;
            imageMemoryBarrier.image = texture.image;
            imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange = subresourceRange;
            imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED;
            imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

            // Insert a memory dependency at the proper pipeline stages that will execute the image layout transition
            // Source pipeline stage is host write/read execution (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT)
            // Destination pipeline stage fragment shader access (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT)
            vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
                copyCmd,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                0,
                0, nullptr,
                0, nullptr,
                1, &imageMemoryBarrier);

            vulkanDevice->flushCommandBuffer(copyCmd, queue, true);
        }
)
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM` format is supported? The Vulkan [spec](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.2/html/chap33.html#features-required-format-support) doesn't guarantee that it is. Often 888 formats are not supported, because 8, 88 and 8888 have much nicer alignment than 888, also `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` often has very limited support. You can query format support with `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties`.

Comment: I try it. The format is supported. It seems that it work correctly when memcpy row by row.Thanks a lot.